# Наследование WebViewClient и Fragment

Tags: java, android

Добрый день имеется код:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

        WebView Browser = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        Browser.loadUrl("http://somesite.ru");
        return v;
    }
}
```

Это код фрагмента, который отображается на основной активности. Здесь создаётся и инициализируется объект класса `WebView`. Проблема в том что при нажатии на любою ссылку открывается родной браузер. Чтобы это обойти мне нужно наследовать класс `Fragment1` от класса `WebViewClient`. Что собственно не возможно. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

В общем я дико извиняюсь. Нужно было ещё немного подумать, а не задавать сразу вопрос. Вот решение:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    WebView Browser ;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

        Browser = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        Browser.setWebViewClient(new webClient());

        Browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Browser.loadUrl("http://somesite.ru");
        return v;
    }
    class webClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Browser.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс нужно было вложить.